# Am I wiring this sensor / wheatstone bridge correctly?

Tags: wheatstone-bridge, gas-sensor

I have a methane sensor ([MP7227-DA](https://sgx.cdistore.com/datasheets/sgx/mp7227-da%20rev.1.pdf)) that gives the following schematic:
[image]

I've assumed R1 and R2 = (C) and (D) in the diagram, R3 and R4 are resistors which are equal and make up the other side of the bridge and R5 is optional if you want to try and 0 out the methane readings (instead of R5, I do this programatically). For R3 and R4, I'm using 0.1% resistors. The LDO I'm using for the 3.0V feed is extremely low noise / stable and the V+/- that come out of the bridge feed into an I-amp.

Here's how I've gone ahead and wired this up:
[image]

I am still seeing significant variability in the methane readings due to temperature changes. I thought one of the advantages of a wheatstone was to minimize effects of temperature on the circuit. I figured maybe I was doing something wrong?

Comment: > "Since the two devices are generally a different colour, they have different emissivity and hence different slope resistances. Therefore, to obtain the best temperature performance, it is necessary on occasion to connect a fixed resistor in parallel with the compensator to correct for its higher slope resistance." (from the datasheet). Have you looked into this? Your wiring otherwise looks OK to me.

Comment: Interesting, I somehow missed that line. So this fixed resistor (Rt in their diagram) is needed "on occasion"... I haven't looked into this. I'm trying to make quite a few of these and don't have a way of manually inserting a resistor in parallel depending on how a specific sensor is behaving.

My best bet is perhaps to just always add in a 20k in parallel to the compensator and hope that improves performance across the board?

Comment: A small screwdriver-turned trimpot can make it easier to adjust or calibrate when necessary. You can combine with series or parallel fixed resistances to ensure it stays within a specific range if needed.